# AddTo regression in version 10

Tags: bugs, compatibility, upvalues

**Bug (of `Interval`) introduced in 10, persisting through 12.2.**

---

As we know we can assign special addition rules to symbols by using `UpValues`:

```
ClearAll[mySymbol]
mySymbol /: mySymbol + x_ := {mySymbol, x}
```

They are used when we directly add something to `mySymbol`

```
mySymbol + 5
(* {mySymbol, 5} *)
mySymbol + mySymbol
(* {mySymbol, mySymbol} *)
```

but also when we use some other functions as `+=` ([`AddTo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AddTo.html)):

```
ClearAll[tmp]
tmp = mySymbol;
tmp += 5
(* {mySymbol, 5} *)
tmp
(* {mySymbol, 5} *)
```

In *Mathematica* versions 8 and 9 it also worked when we added expression to itself:

```
$Version
(* "9.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (February 7, 2013)" *)
ClearAll[tmp]
tmp = mySymbol;
tmp += mySymbol
(* {mySymbol, mySymbol} *)
tmp
(* {mySymbol, mySymbol} *)
```

In versions 10.0, 10.1 and 10.2 it doesn't work like that anymore and `AddTo`, when adding same expressions, always returns 2 times expression even if `Plus` was overridden.

```
$Version
(* "10.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)" *)
ClearAll[tmp]
tmp = mySymbol;
tmp += mySymbol
(* 2 mySymbol *)
tmp
(* 2 mySymbol *)
```

**Is this a bug, or should we not rely on overridden `Plus` when using functions like `AddTo` and override them separately?**

---

**Edit**

It seems some built-ins, like `Interval`, relied on this and are broken in v10:

```
$Version
(* "10.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)" *)
ClearAll[tmp]
tmp = Interval[{0, 1}, {4, 5}];
tmp + tmp
(* Interval[{0, 2}, {4, 6}, {8, 10}] *)
tmp += tmp
(* Interval[{0, 2}, {8, 10}] *)
```

Comment: I'd say the latter, because relying on `AddTo` picking up `Plus` overloading is relying on implementation details, namely that `AddTwo` uses `Plus` behind the scene. This may be so (as it was before), or may be not (as it apparently is now), but one can't really rely on this relation.

Comment: @Leonid While I don't disagree regarding user defined functions. There seems to be a bug related to this in `Interval` implementation.

Comment: As @Leonid says, before version 10, `AddTo` used the top-level equivalents of `Set` and `Plus`, thus calling the evaluator, which caused serious inefficiencies. They have now been corrected.

Comment: Well, then ask a question about that bug :) Oh, I see you did.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin - I do think one should be able to rely on it given the line from the docs: "x+=dx is equivalent to x=x+dx." I can see there are arguments both ways - the docs represent the language before any modifications are made to it - but it's a bit misleading in this case. It breaks the expectation that the symbol `+=` is linked to the symbol `+`, which is an extremely reasonable assumption to make.

Comment: @ilian Thanks for the insight. Do you think that issue with `Interval` in edited question counts as a bug?

Comment: @PatrickStevens I disagree. "Equivalent" here means that you get equivalent result, not that one function actually calls the other. You really can't rely on that, unless it is stated in the docs that *function A actually calls function B*. `Plus` and `AddTwo` are parts of the interface, and your assumption already is about implementation.

Comment: Yes, I think the `Interval` example is a bug and filed a report. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @ilian already answered, but yes, looks like a bug to me as well.

Comment: @Leonid, @ ilian thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Hold` to simulate the behavior you originally had

```
$Version

(* "10.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 7, 2015)" *)

ClearAll[mySymbol]
mySymbol /: mySymbol + x_ := {mySymbol, x}
mySymbol /: mySymbol + Hold[x_] := {mySymbol, x}

tmp = mySymbol;
tmp += 5

(* {mySymbol, 5} *)

tmp = mySymbol;
tmp += Hold[mySymbol]

(* {mySymbol, mySymbol} *)
```